# Dell Perc 5/i battery replacement - how long until it registers as good?

Tags: dell-perc, battery, dell-openmanage

So I replaced the battery for my Dell Perc 5/i controller since the machine had an error code that it needed to be replaced.  I ordered the battery directly from dell based on the service code and installed it without issue.

In open manage it still showed as an issue, so I chose the option to learn under I went in to Dell Open Manage and told it to Learn/Cycle Storage->Perc->Battery->Tasks (it was the only option).

That was approximately 1 week ago!   It said it could take 72 hours, but it's still going.  This is the current status:

```
 Battery on Controller PERC 5/i Integrated  

Name Battery 0 
State Learning 
Predicted Capacity Status Unknown 
Learn State Active 
Next Learn Time 0 hours 
Maximum Learn Delay 7 days 0 hours 
Battery Tasks No Task Available
```

Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 3):

I replaced batterys on 4 diffrent perc 5/i controllers just a week ago.
It took about 12-24 hours to show up as OK state.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible you got a bad battery. It trickle charges most likely at a very low voltage right? So I'd expect anywhere from 24 to 36 hours, maybe less. It could simply be reading the state wrong, try a cold shutdown of the server and power it back on and see if it persists. Then call Dell and get another battery sent out.

Answer (score 1):

It could also be the controller or it's firmware. Have had a few like that.

Comment: Never had a faulty controller myself, but if a second replacement battery does the same thing that would be my next suspect.