# New Dell Perc 5/i battery shows as failed after installation

Tags: dell-poweredge, dell-perc

**PROBLEM**

I am running into an issue where I Replaced the PERC 5/i RAID Controller battery of my Dell 2950 Rack server twice and in both instances the Server Administrator reports the battery as failed.

**WHAT I DID SO FAR**

When I first noticed that the battery has failed I purchased a new brand new OEM one. After installation it still was reported as failed so I started a learn cycle since this was my only option. After a week or so it was still learning.

I found [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/309755/dell-perc-5-i-battery-replacement-how-long-until-it-registers-as-good) thread which seemed to be the exact same problem I am experiencing but it's 3 years old and the suggested solutions (cold shutdown) did not help.

I then purchased a new battery from another vendor (again new and DELL OEM), installed it and same situation. So it seems unlikely that it's a battery problem.

All other components in the server seem to be fine and the server is operational and in production. Drivers and firmware are up-to-date.

**QUESTION**

Does anybody have an idea what the problem might be or how I can figure out and handle the cause of this failure?

Comment: I've seen this caused by a bad memory module on the controller.

Comment: Interesting. Do you know if there is a way to test for this?

Comment: I have had weird errors persist on Dell hardware a few times until the embedded system management log (ESM) is cleared.  Instructions on how to do so are at:  [How to clear the ESM log on a Dell PowerEdge server](http://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/19/SLN132517/EN/).

Comment: @yoonix: Thank you for your time. I cleared the logs using OMSA. I will see if this solved the problem after the learning cycle is done. I will report back here at this point.

Comment: @yoonix: Thank you for your help. Clearing the log & rebooting resolved the issue.